# How to run unit tests before building a ruby gem?

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am developing a gem and I have my unit tests in lib/spec directory. Currently I manually run unit tests using `rspec lib/spec`. And then I build gem using `gem build mygem.gemspec` (which builds a **.gem** file).

How can I run my unit tests along with gem build command? (Just like how we do production builds using npm)

Comment: Try rake, and let the build task depend on the test task. If the test process returns non-zero, the build task won't run, which is the effect I assume you are requesting. And major congrats for writing tests; they make all the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a build process that consists of multiple tasks (e.g. testing, creating a gem, publishing a gem), and has dependencies between those tasks (e.g. the gem should only be created if the tests are successful, in order to publish the gem, it needs to be created first), you can use a *build tool* to automate that.

Actually, build tools can be used for much more than just building, which is why some people prefer the term *task-oriented programming* or (my personal favority) *dependency-oriented programming* for that.

The most famous of such dependency-oriented programming tools is probably [`make`](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)). If you are familiar with the Java ecosystem, you probably know [Apache Ant](https://ant.apache.org/) and [Gradle](https://gradle.org/). In the Microsoft world, there is the [Microsoft Build Engine (MSBuild)](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild). From the ECMAScript ecosystem, you may know [Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) or [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com/). The hot new kid on the block is Google's [Bazel](https://bazel.build/).

Ruby also has its own share of such tools, the most widely-used one is [Rake](https://ruby.github.io/rake/).

A lot of Ruby libraries and tools come with their own ready-made Rake Tasks, so that you don't have to write them yourself. For your particular use case, for example, there are ready-made tasks for building gems and for running RSpec tests.